# Name of ideology where 'thinking of something wrong is actually wrong'

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, phrase-meaning

I am thinking of the name of some kind of ideology where in a world where by the mere fact of thinking of doing something that is wrong causes you to actually be in the wrong.

e.g.

> 1. In a hypothetical universe where your consciousness can be read by authority you could be held accountable for thinking of doing something wrong.
> 2. Some religions may enforce a similar idea where you may be judged based on your thoughts.
> 3. The opposite of, you are only held accountable if you commit the act, not because it was a thought (unless they had a detailed plan of you actually going to commit it).

Comment: I vaguely recall references to this point of view when I was reading Elaine Pagels book on the Gnostic Gospels recently.  But the references (if I'm remembering correctly) were pretty vague and limited.  However, you may find what you're looking for if you research early Christian theology.

Comment: I don't know, but we're going to have to call the Thought Police because you have been thinking about this.

Comment: You are accused of heresy on three counts -- heresy by **thought**, heresy by word, heresy by deed, and heresy by action -- *four* counts.  I'll come in again.

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me of the Thought Police and double-think in *1984* by George Orwell.

There is also a section of the Sermon on the Mount in Matthew 5 where Jesus is preaching on Hebrew teachings and taking the ethics impossibly high. There's a repetition of, "You have heard it said that..." (state a Hebrew law here) "but I say that..." (state a higher ethic here). For example, here's the take on murder in Matthew 5:21-22:

> 21 “You have heard that it was said to those of old, ‘You shall not murder; and whoever murders will be liable to judgment.’ 22 But I say to you that everyone who is angry with his brother will be liable to judgment; whoever insults his brother will be liable to the council; and whoever says, ‘You fool!’ will be liable to the hell of fire." (ESV)

Bear in mind that the common understanding of this entire sermon is that Jesus preaches the highest ethic coupled with complete grace. The point is that no one can save himself by abiding by a set of laws perfectly, because no one could ever do that. So I would hesitate to take this as an example of the Christian ideology as a whole, but it seems to fit with what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

This is the sort of thinking that happens when you've descended into *[scrupulosity](http://www.catholic.com/magazine/articles/scrupulosity-the-occupational-hazard-of-the-catholic-moral-life)*.

(The linked article in *Catholic Answers Magazine* describes scrupulosity as "the occupational hazard of the Catholic moral life"):

> The scrupulous person may believe that having even a fleeting impure
>   thought (maybe sexual thoughts or thought about revenge) is sinful. He
>   may believe that we are able to control our minds completely, so that
>   if anything impure enters it has been freely chosen and therefore
>   sinful.

Answer (score 2):

Other people have mentioned Orwell's *1984,* but not the actual term used therein for this offense, *[thoughtcrime](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/thoughtcrime)*:

> An instance of unorthodox or controversial thinking, considered as a
>   criminal offense or as socially unacceptable:  thoughtcrimes are
>   notoriously difficult to prosecute (Oxford Dictionaries)

People also use the spaced-out spelling "thought crime." I think it fits what you're describing pretty well. But technically speaking, this is the name of the offense, and you asked for the name of the ideology that condemns it. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoughtcrime) on the subject describes it as a concept that belongs to "totalitarian regimes" that are enforcing "ideological correctness." So the name for the corresponding ideology would be *[totalitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarianism)* (at least, if you're talking about a political system).